# Context initialization fails when initializing bean that extends class inside jar

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm trying to initialize a bean using my applicationContext.xml, but it fails to initialize probably because the class that is being initialized is extending an abstract class sitting inside a jar.

So inside my main project's applicationContext, I have the following:

```
<bean id="TestMessageListener" class="za.co.mycee.core.util.Test" />
```

My Test.java is as follow:

```
package za.co.mycee.core.util;

import org.springframework.amqp.core.AmqpTemplate;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Message;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import za.co.mycee.messaging.model.TestRequest;
import za.co.mycee.messaging.model.TestResponse;
import za.co.mycee.messaging.service.TestService;

import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;

public class Test extends TestService {

    @Autowired
    private AmqpTemplate template;

    @Override
    protected String getQueue() {
        return "test";
    }

    @Override
    protected String getExchange() {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<TestRequest> getRequestType() {
        return TestRequest.class;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<TestResponse> getResponseType() {
        return TestResponse.class;
    }

    @Override
    protected AmqpTemplate getTemplate() {
        return this.template;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message, Channel channel) throws Exception {

        System.out.println(" >> " + new String(message.getBody()));

    }

}
```

and the full exception I'm getting after doing a mvn tomcat:run

```
2013-12-13 15:45:46,031 [main] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [za.co.mycee.core.util.Test] for bean with name 'TestMessageListener' defined in file [C:\Code\SpringSource\sts-4.3.1.RELEASE\sts-3.4.0.RELEASE\mycee\mycee-core\target\classes\META-INF\spring\applicationContext.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: za/co/mycee/messaging/service/TestService
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1266)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1332)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:898)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:588)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.start(Embedded.java:825)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:558)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:255)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: za/co/mycee/messaging/service/TestService
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1141)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1612)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:258)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:415)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1284)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1255)
        ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: za.co.mycee.messaging.service.TestService
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
        ... 55 more
Dec 13, 2013 3:45:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [za.co.mycee.core.util.Test] for bean with name 'TestMessageListener' defined in file [C:\Code\SpringSource\sts-4.3.1.RELEASE\sts-3.4.0.RELEASE\mycee\mycee-core\target\classes\META-INF\spring\applicationContext.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: za/co/mycee/messaging/service/TestService
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1266)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1332)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:898)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:588)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.start(Embedded.java:825)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:558)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:255)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: za/co/mycee/messaging/service/TestService
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1141)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1612)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:258)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:415)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1284)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1255)
        ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: za.co.mycee.messaging.service.TestService
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
        ... 55 more

Dec 13, 2013 3:45:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Dec 13, 2013 3:45:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/mycee-core] startup failed due to previous errors
Dec 13, 2013 3:45:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

Obviously if I remove the extends TestService and remove all the @Override, then it runs, but then I can re-use the code sitting inside TestService.
How do I make it aware of the TestService sitting inside the jar and get rid of the error?

**Update**: As Frederic have rightfully pointed out, mycee-messaging.jar is not in my classpath, when I build a war file and look in WEB-INF/lib, there's no mycee-messaging.jar.

So in my pom.xml, I have:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>za.co.mycee</groupId>
    <artifactId>mycee-messaging</artifactId>
    <version>${mycee.messaging}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

When I do mvn eclipse:eclipse, and refresh mycee-core, the project mycee-messaging is listed under projects and eclipse seems to be fine with it, but it's not listed under under libraries.

Checking .m2/repository/za/co/mycee/mycee-messaging/1.0.1, I can see mycee-messaging-1.0.1.jar as well as mycee-messaging-1.0.1.pom, so mvn clean install did its job correctly.

Do I need to add something else to my pom.xml in order for maven to include that jar in the war file?

**Solution**: Remove the scope tag

Some good reading material to understand why the scope provided is doing what it's doing:
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Dependency+Scopes

Comment: are you sure that jar is in the class-path ? do you find it in WEB-INF/lib ?   as it seems to be test classes and if you are using doesn't that jar have the scope test ?

Comment: Hi Frederick, that Test class is not part of unit testing, I should have called it something other than Test.java.
I just built a war-file and I don't see mycee-messaging.jar in WEB-INF/lib, so now I guess it becomes a maven issue and not a Spring issue.

Comment: ok problem solved then :-)

Comment: Updated my question, I'm probably missing something in my pom.xml, any ideas?

Comment: remove  <scope>provided</scope>

Comment: Sweet, that fixes it, I'll need to do a bit more reading on the scope tag, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <scope>provided</scope>
```

means that you expect the dependency to be provided for you by in this case your tomcat container, so maven will not bundle it for you in your war.

more info from the maven doc:

> Scope provided is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK
>   or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when
>   building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would
>   set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to
>   scope provided because the web container provides those classes. This
>   scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is
>   not transitive.